# Широта значений понятия "декрет"

Tags: лексика

Можно ли назвать конституционные акты советского правительства декретами? "Декреты" относятся главным образом к законодательным актам СССР или сейчас это слово может быть употребимо так же и имеет хождение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Осталось разговорное хождение слова "**декрет**": это неформальное сокращение от "*декретный отпуск*" (ныне "отпуск по беременности и родам"), выражения, которое оставалось последней ссылкой на "декреты" (указы и постановления Советской власти до конституции 1936 года) в законах о труде.